# ifelse function, strings to binary

Tags: r

I am trying to take a column from a dataset which has strings of either 2 or more lengths.

For instance:

```
Col1.  Col2.   Col3.  Col4.  
XX     XX      XX     XX
XX     XX      XXGH   XX
XX     XX      XXGHO  XX
XX     XX      XX     XX
...and so on.
```

I'd like to convert Col3 into Col5, taking the strings in the column and turning them into 1s and 0s, where greater than 2 string lengths is 1 and 2 string lengths is 0.

I am trying to use ifelse, but I am not really getting anywhere.

It should end up looking something like this:

```
Col1.  Col2.   Col3.  Col4.  Col5
XX     XX      XX     XX     0 
XX     XX      XXGH   XX     1
XX     XX      XXGHO  XX     1
XX     XX      XX     XX     0
```

where Col5 is the 1 and 0 equivalent of Col3.

Comment: It would help if you provided `Col5` (i.e., expected output).

Comment: ... but perhaps no `ifelse` required: `+(nchar(c("XX", "XXGH", "XXGHO", "XX")) > 2)` (aka `+(nchar(dat$Col3.) > 2)`).

Comment: I edited the above for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **base R** you can try this

```
dat$Col5. <- as.numeric( nchar( as.character(dat$Col3.) ) > 2 )

  Col1. Col2. Col3. Col4. Col5.
1    XX    XX    XX    XX     0
2    XX    XX  XXGH    XX     1
3    XX    XX XXGHO    XX     1
4    XX    XX    XX    XX     0
```

Comment: I got: Error in nchar(dat$Col3.) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Comment: @Noob3000 Then Col3. is not a character column. But you can cast it. See edit.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `str_length()`

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- tibble(
  Col3 = c('XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'XXGH', 'XXGHO', 'XX')
)

foo %>%
  mutate(Col5 = ifelse(str_length(Col3) > 2, 1, 0))
```

Comment: If I use that, would I have to go through the entire column and write in all the values?
```
Col3 = c('XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'XXGH', 'XXGHO', 'XX' ...and so on.)
```

Comment: I was just providing an example dataset in R code since you didn't provide that for us. The only part that was relevant for the answer were the last two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

For simple comparisons, `ifelse` isn't needed

Here we check if the number of characters is greater than 2 and multiply the `TRUE/FALSE` response by "1" to give a numerical response

```
foo$Col5 <- (nchar(foo$Col3) > 2) * 1
```

Comment: It returns an error saying 'Error in nchar(foo$Col3):  nchar() requires a character vector'.